# Auto Layout iphone 4 - 6plus

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Since apple has now introduced the iPhone 6 + 6 plus. How would I make the image for different sizes of phones? For iPhone 4 and 5/5s/5c you would do

```
    #define IS_568_SCREEN (fabs((double) [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)568) < DBL_EPSLION)

    if(IS_568_SCREEN) {
//Iphone 5/5s/5c 
} else {
//iphone 4s }
```

But how would you do it for iPhone 4s to iPhone 6 plus? Also my auto layout isn't working very well. Im trying to change the size for all my objects dependent of the phone and using auto layout to place them correctly. However its not working out, I'm doing "height", "leading space to Container Margin", "Bottom Space To Bottom layout" and "Trailing space to container". As this will be a little hard and time consuming for all the objects sizes, can I use multiple storyboards? and what I mean by that is can I have one storyboard file for iPhone 6, then one for iPhone 6 plus etc. Or if not whats the proper way of doing auto layout on the interface builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to what I was looking for, nothing complicated :)

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    if (screenHeight == 480) {
        // do iPhone 4s stuff
    } else if (screenHeight == 568) {
        // do iPhone 5, 5s, 5c stuff
    } else if (screenHeight == 667) {
        // do iPhone 6 stuff
    } else if (screenHeight == 736) {
        //do iPhone 6 plus stuff
    }
```